# design an algorithm to do queries within a log file

Tags: algorithm

I was recently asked this question in an interview: 
Given a log file which has customer id and corresponding to that id it has a page id visited by that customer. Given such log files for 3 consecutive days, design an algo to find those customers who visited the site on exactly 2 out of 3 days and visited at least 3 distinct pages. Discuss the design and space complexity.

I thought of this approach:
1)sorting the 3 log files 
2) looking through the top of each file: look for the same customer ids and see the number of different days they visited the pages. If the same customer has visited the pages on 3 different days, then we can discard that customer and move on looking to the next customer in each file. Else, if this customer has visited the the pages on exactly 2 different days, we will keep storing his page ids in a set. We can finally check whether this set has 3 distinct pages or not.

But, I am not sure whether this approach is the most efficient, also what will be the approach which will scale well if I have to find k visited sites out of K sites, visiting exactly N distinct pages. I thought that k-d trees(2-d trees) may help because they can handle multiple queries.

So, what will be the best data strucuture and the algorithm to handle these kinds of queries.

Comment: It looks extremely similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289479/algorithm-for-retrieving-data-from-log-files)

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of (Id,day,page) tuples. Sort lexicographically. Now each customer's accesses are consecutive in the list, and the questions are easy to answer with a single scan. The time complexity is that of sorting the data - O(n log n).

Comment: Seems like a better approach than mine. Essentially using a radix sort on the tuples. But would sorting the data lexicographically be (a*n + b*n + c*n)? Where "a" is number number of customer ids (assuimg they are sequential, if not then much worse), "b" is number of days, and "c" is number of pages.

This seems like a more space efficient approach than mine but your constants could really kill your speed efficiency.

Comment: Good enough solution. But for each customer id, we will have to create a set of days and set of page ids, which he visited. If number of days is exactly 2, then we can check in the set of page ids whether it has atleast 3 pages. The size of the 2 sets to track days and page id may increase to N(worst case) if we have to find N visited sites in exactly M different days, in which case the solution does not scale well in terms of space. Even the previous answer(2 hashes solution), suffers from the same problem.

Comment: You're right. I modify the solution as follows. You make two lists of pairs, one (id,day) and one (id, day) and one (id,page). Sort them and delete duplicates. Now scan both list simultaneously. The complexity is still that of sorting and you don't need more than the space for the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd approaching it using two HashMaps. The first hash would map from customer id to a Set containing the days visited. The second Hash would map from customer id to a Set of pages visited. After passing through the log files once, you'll have populated both Hashes. You'll have to pass thru the first Hash once to determine who visited exactly twice (using the Set size to do that). For every customer who passes the first test, look-up the customer id in the second Hash and see who visited at least 3 distinct pages (using the Set size to do that).

This would be fairly quick but require a good amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data base question.
You have `2` entities: `Customer(ID)` and `Page(ID)`.
You also have `1` relationship between them that we will call `Visited` with a `date` attribute.
But if we must...

Use a `Set` to store the different `Page ID`'s.
Use a `Dictionary` with the `key` as `Customer ID` and `value` will have `2` properties:
1) A `Set` of `Page ID`'s.
2) A `Set` of `Date`'s.

This model gives you access to each `Customer` in `O(lgn)` and the number of different `Date`'s that were visited by that `Customer` in `O(1)` and the number of `Page`'s in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remember minimal state per client:

```
 struct client_state {
 day1 :1;
 day2 :1;
 day3 :1;
 npage :2;
 page_id pages[2];
 };
```

For every {client_id, day, page_id} tuple you have to perform the following steps:

```
0) lookup client record (see below)
1) switch(day) {
     case day1: day1=1; break;
     case day2: day2=1; break;
     case day3: day3=1; break;
     }
2) switch(npage) {
     case 3: break;
     case 2: if (pages[1] == page_id) break;
     case 1: if (pages[0] == page_id) break;
     case 0: pages[npage++] = page_id; break;
     }
```

- If everything fits in memory, the state can be kept in a hashtable, with client_id as key. A second final pass is needed: inspect all status-records and filter on {day1,day2,day3} and (npage==3) Complexity is two sequential passes. (O(N))
- Otherwise, the file has to be sorted (O Nlog(N)) and the sorted file can be used to sequentially update the state-record (we only need one!), Filtering can be done at end-of-group.